# nodejs + qunit: saving returned exception in test

Tags: javascript, node.js, qunit

I'm new to qunit (one day) and still learning..

I would like to save the message and stacktrace from an exception. I'm not sure how to do that.

In the code below, copies of stacktrace and message are places in the variables. I'm assuming the scope is different.

```
QUnit.test("Internal scheme validator - destination list - empty - no strict", function(assert) {
var path ='[{"sid":"test_scheme0","ssch":"","dstli":""}]';
var pathi = JSON.parse(path);
var expected = 'undefined scheme destination list';
var err;
var enm;
var emsg;
var estk;
assert.throws(
    function(){
        "use strict";
        sysCatalog.__vschi__(pathi,"SchemeTest Ignore Message" );
    },
    function(e){
        err= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e));
        enm= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e.name));
        emsg = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e.message));
        estk = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e.stack));
        return emsg === expected;
    },
    'Wrong exception message returned.\nExpected: '+ expected+'\nActual: '+ emsg +'\nBacktrace:\n'+estk
);
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a little bit of rethinking.. The quinit exception mechanism is a bit rudimentary for my needs.. This is the solution I reverted to, which is the test code started with before moving to qunit.

There is one drawback, qunit will dump the backtrace if:

> QUnit.config.notrycatch = true;

```
    QUnit.test("Internal scheme validator - destination list - empty - strict", function(assert) {
    var path ='[{"sid":"test_scheme0","ssch":"","dstli":""}]';
    var pathi = JSON.parse(path);
    var expected = 'zero length scheme destination list';
    var enm;
    var emsg;
    var estk;
    try{
        sysCatalog.__vschi__(pathi,"SchemeTest Ignore Message",true );
    }catch(e){
        // here the test failed and we should not proceed
        //cc=false;
        enm= e.name;
        emsg = e.message;
        estk = e.stack;
    }
    assert.strictEqual(emsg,expected, 'Wrong exception message returned.\nBacktrace:\n'+estk);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to save your results. If you want to output the errors and stacktraces to a file then you can use the [fs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) api in node to save your results to a nicely formatted file.

```
fs.writeFile(...);
```

Additionally there is a module that integrates with [qunit and node](https://github.com/JamesMGreene/qunit-reporter-junit) that lets you output your results to an XML file.

Comment: Yes, but its not placed in any qunit test report. I did work out how to achieve the goal..